# MongoDB Nested Documents Aggregation using Change Events

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, mongodb, nosql

The problem is that when I push a new document inside the array field it becomes a dotted notation.

> What I am trying to achieve is to filter the the response of the Change Event or the Collection.watch().

[image: This the okay version]

> But this happens

[image]

> There is no way that I can access the updateDescription.updatedFields.message because it became a dot notation.

I tried to use

```
var filter = [{
    $match: {
        $and: [
            { 'documentKey._id': req.body.id },
            {'updateDescription.updatedFields.message': // value of current length of the messages array}
        ]
    }
  }];
```

and

```
var filter = [{
    $match: {
        $and: [
            { 'documentKey._id': req.body.id },
            {'updateDescription.updatedFields.messages' : {$exists: true}}
        ]
    }
  }];
```

I also used projection:

```
try{
    res.status(200).set({
      "connection":"keep-alive",
      "cache-control": "no-cache",
      "content-type":"application/json"
    });
  var query = await User.findOne({'_id': req.body.id});
  var len = parseInt(query['messages'].length);
  var _str = 'messages.'+String(len);
  console.log(_str)
  var project = [{$project: {'updateDescription.updatedFields' : {$objectToArray: '$updateDescription.updatedFields'}}}]
  var filter = [{
    $match: {
        $and: [
            { 'documentKey._id': req.body.id },
            {'updateDescription.updatedFields.k': _str}
        ]
    }
  }];

  await User.watch(filter, project).on('change', data => console.log(data))

  }catch(err){
    res.status(500).send(err);
  }
```

But still I haven't got any solution how to solve this.

Comment: So you always want to return only the last element of the array, or do you want to specify which element to return?

Comment: @Joe somewhat. I want to return the field inside the updateDocument.updatedField if it’s only messages.

Comment: You could use a regex to match any update within the messages array:  `{"updateDescription.updatedFields.k":{$regex:"^messages"}}`

Comment: @Joe Apparently the regex doesn't work either. It doesn't return any fields or document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are projecting it wrong.

```
$project: {'updateDescription.updatedFields' : {$objectToArray: '$updateDescription.updatedFields'}}
```

is should be

```
{$project: { 'updateDescription.updatedFields' : {$objectToArray: '$updateDescription.updatedFields'}, 'documentKey._id': req.body.id  }}
```

Then you go use regex on the $match

```
{$match: {
    $and: [
       { 'documentKey._id': req.body.id },
       {'updateDescription.updatedFields.k': {$regex:"^matches"}}
   ]}
```

Here's the full working snippet:

```
  try{
    res.status(200).set({
      "connection":"keep-alive",
      "cache-control": "no-cache",
      "content-type":"application/json"
    });

  var filter = [
    {$project: { 'updateDescription.updatedFields' : {$objectToArray: '$updateDescription.updatedFields'}, 'documentKey._id': req.body.id  }},
    {$match: {
        $and: [
            { 'documentKey._id': req.body.id },
            {'updateDescription.updatedFields.k': {$regex:"^matches"}}
        ]
    }
  }];

  await User.watch(filter).on('change', data => console.log(data.updateDescription.updatedFields))

  }catch(err){
    res.status(500).send(err);
  }
```

The reason why it's not matching is because you are using $and operator and there's no "documentKey._id" to match with since you projected it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The `$filter` and `$project` stages should be together in a single array.  The `watch` function takes (Pipeline Array, Options Object). Try:

```
  var filter = [
    {$project: {'updateDescription.updatedFields' : {$objectToArray: '$updateDescription.updatedFields'}}},
    {$match: {
        $and: [
            { 'documentKey._id': req.body.id },
            {'updateDescription.updatedFields.k': _str}
        ]
    }
  }];

await User.watch(filter).on('change', data => console.log(data))
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem that I am having. It still returns unwanted fields. Instead of messages only.

Comment: This is a change stream, not an aggregation.  The pipeline you pass to `watch` is only used to match the change events in order to filter which events are returned.  The pipeline stages do not actually make modifications to the event.